# Vue.js class bindings, inserts empty space between css classes

Tags: html, css, vue.js, web-frontend

I am using a `v-bind:class` binding on a component, with the goal of turning a `css` class on and off depending on the truthiness of a `boolean` in my **`Vue.js`** component.

When I in my **template declare:**

```
<aside v-bind:class="{'--opened':sidebarVisible}" class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
```

Script part of my **component**:

```
<script>
import { EventBus } from "@/event-bus.ts";
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                sidebarVisible:false
            }                
        }    
        //Cut for breavity            
};      

</script>
```

I expect **`Vue.js`** to modify the class to `class="sidebar--opened"` but instead I get `class="sidebar --opened"` (with an empty space between sidebar and --opened). How can I get around this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to give it full name of the class as this line will add a separate class to it. so the solution would be

```
<aside v-bind:class="{'sidebar--opened':sidebarVisible}" class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
```

Note: If it doesn't work then you might have to remove class 'sidebar' explicitly.

Comment: Thank you, this works. It's true that i now get class='sidebar sidebar--opened', but that we can deal with. Accepted.